# Auto Login even after browser close in yii

Tags: php, yii

Sorry because my English is not good. here is my confusion, I am trying to create cookie based Login in Yii, I have below code in main.php

```
 'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
```

and in LoginForm.php

```
public function login()
{
        if($this->_identity===null)
        {
            $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->userName,$this->password);
            $this->_identity->errorCode = $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
        if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
        {   
            $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 :0; // 30 days
            Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```

But when I Loged in into site, and after browser close, user get loged out, So can you please help me to stay user loged in even after browser close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have "Remember Me" checkbox in your login form.
Try following code at LoginForm.php

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->userName,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->errorCode = $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {   
        // $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 :0; // 30 days
        $duration = 3600*24*30; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**APPEND**

Or please check "[session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)" value in php.ini

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 2592000
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have "Remember Me" checkbox in Login form.

Comment: @Sanjay Then, Can you check which value is set to $duration by printing the value?

Comment: $duration printing 2592000, I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Sanjay which browser are you using?

Comment: @Sanjay Or Please check session.cookie-lifetime value in php.ini. see : http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Answer (score 0):

Change your model function as like below this worked for me

```
public function login()
{
  if ($this->_identity === NULL)
  {
    $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->login, $this->password);
    $this->_identity->authenticate();
  }
  if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
  {
    $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0; // 30 days
    Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration);
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
    return FALSE;
}
```

You havent checked for remember me option which is checked while login.

As well as your controler action should be like this

```
public function actionLogin()
{
$model = new LoginForm;

// if it is ajax validation request
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form')
{
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
    Yii::app()->end();
}

// collect user input data
if (isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
{
    $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
    // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
    if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
}
// display the login form
$this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```